# Cannot get a CSS property value of a flexible element with Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to get CSS `width` property of a flexible element, but for some reason it doesn't work:

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pLEwdp?editors=1010

---

#### Code:

```html
<v-layout>
  <h2 class="pa-3">non-flex</h2>

  <v-spacer class="flexible-area grey" ref="flexibleArea">
    <h2 class="pa-3">current width is: {{flexibleAreaWidth}}</h2>
  </v-spacer>

  <h2 class="pa-3">non-flex</h2>
</v-layout>

...

computed: {
  flexibleAreaWidth () {
    let elem = this.$refs.flexibleArea
    return window.getComputedStyle(elem,null).getPropertyValue("width")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because [`$refs` are only available **after** render (mount)](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref) (emphasis mine):

> An important note about the ref registration timing: because the refs themselves are created as a result of the render function, you cannot access them on the initial render - **they don’t exist yet!** `$refs` is also non-reactive, therefore you should not attempt to use it in templates for data-binding.

And that `computed` you declared is executed before mount.

In other words, you'll want your `computed` to execute only after mount.

To test that, you could check the **internal** variable `this._isMounted`. But, since it is internal (and non-reactive), you *really* want to keep a `this.isMounted` variable yourself, as shown below.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {isMounted: false},
  mounted() {
    this.isMounted = true;
  },
  computed: {
    flexibleAreaWidth () {
      if (!this.isMounted) return null;
      let elem = this.$refs.flexibleArea;
      return window.getComputedStyle(elem,null).getPropertyValue("width")
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700|Material+Icons'>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://unpkg.com/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'>
<script src='https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://unpkg.com/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.js'></script>

<div id="app" >
  <v-app id="inner">
    <v-layout>
      <h2 class="pa-3">non-flex</h2>
      <v-spacer class="flexible-area grey" ref="flexibleArea">
        <h2 class="pa-3">current width is: {{flexibleAreaWidth}}</h2>
      </v-spacer>
      <h2 class="pa-3">non-flex</h2>
    </v-layout>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But why doesn't the value getting updated on width change? I want another element to take the width of this element. Is that because `**$refs**  is also non-reactive`?

Comment: Because it is not reactive. You could set a timer to check if it updated.

Comment: Hmm, is there no simplistic way to bind this `width` property dynamically to `width` of another element?

Comment: I'm not sure about what you want, but it seems like a job for CSS.

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks again for the detailed explanation, it's good to know that I should check if it `isMounted` and that I shouldn't use $refs for these kind of things

Comment: Hey, great to know. You are right, I believe your made a good decision.

Comment: @Un1 I'm happy for you that you figured it out. Would you care to share your solution?

Answer (score 2):

To quote the Vue.js [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Child-Component-Refs):

> $refs are only populated after the component has been rendered, and it is not reactive. It is only meant as an escape hatch for direct child manipulation - you should avoid using $refs in templates or computed properties.

The value isn't available when you're trying to read it.