# alternative for jquery css in vuejs

Tags: css, dom, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm learning vuejs and trying to do all without jquery

I need to get a value of a css style line-height.
In jquery i would do:

```
let x = $(this).css("line-height");
```

How can I get this value using vuejs 2.5?

I was exploring `this.$el` in this structure, but can't find solution to get this value:

```
data: function () {
    return {
        lineHeight: null
    }
},
mounted(){
    this.lineHeight = ?
}
```

Comment: [window.getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

Comment: ^^ example of its use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49331043/cannot-get-a-css-property-value-of-a-flexible-element-with-vue

Comment: specifically, `window.getComputedStyle(this.$el, null)['line-height']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
// with jQuery: $(this).css("line-height");
// with Vue:
mounted() {
    this.lineHeight = window.getComputedStyle(this.$el).getPropertyValue('line-height');
}
```

If the component (`this.$el`) may be inside an iframe or popup, or if you want to be extra careful, read on.

[**JSFiddle demo here.**](https://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/oyf1hxsu/3/)

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    lineHeightTLDR: '',
    lineHeightFull: '',
  },
  mounted(){
      this.lineHeightTLDR = window.getComputedStyle(this.$el).getPropertyValue('line-height');
      this.lineHeightFull = this.css('line-height');
  },
  methods: {
    css(propertyName) {
      let view = this.$el.ownerDocument.defaultView;
      if ( !view || !view.opener ) {
        view = window;
      }
      let computed = view.getComputedStyle(this.$el);
      return computed.getPropertyValue(propertyName) || computed[propertyName];
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <pre>lineHeight tl;dr..: {{ lineHeightTLDR }}</pre>
  <pre>lineHeight full...: {{ lineHeightFull }}</pre>
</div>
```

### Background

Simplest way to mimic jQuery is just to take a look at its [source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/3.3.1/src/css/curCSS.js#L27). The returned value from `.css()` is, roughly:

```
ret = computed.getPropertyValue( name ) || computed[ name ];
```

Which uses [`CSSStyleDeclaration.getPropertyValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/getPropertyValue) on `computed`. And [`computed` is](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/3.3.1/src/css/var/getStyles.js#L4-L16):

```
return function( elem ) {
    var view = elem.ownerDocument.defaultView;
    if ( !view || !view.opener ) {
        view = window;
    }
    return view.getComputedStyle( elem );
}
```

Which uses [`Window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) As you can see, the returned value is something around:

```
ret = view.getComputedStyle(elem).getPropertyValue( name ) || view.getComputedStyle(elem)[name];
```

Where `view` is most probably `window` but could be something else (`elem.ownerDocument.defaultView`).

In the end of the day, if you want to be extra certain and do very close to `jQuery.css()`, use:

```
// with jQuery: $(this).css("line-height");
// with Vue:
mounted(){
    this.lineHeight = this.css('line-height');
},
methods: {
  css(propertyName) {
    let view = elem.ownerDocument.defaultView;
    if ( !view || !view.opener ) {
      view = window;
    }
    let computed = view.getComputedStyle(this.$el);
    ret = computed.getPropertyValue(propertyName) || computed[propertyName];
  }
}
```

But if you know your usage does not rely on iframes or popups (as it is *very* unusual for a Vue instance JavaScript code to run at a window and have the `$el` it is attached to on another), go with the **tl;dr** version.

Comment: **Note:** it doesn't seem possible to mount the Vue instance on an element that is not on the same window (see: https://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/oyf1hxsu/16/ ) so the tl;dr version seems safe enough.

Comment: E ai, deu certo?

Comment: muito bom! valeu!